# Will MVVM Light work with .NET Framework 4.6?

Tags: mvvm-light

I believe the most recent release of MVVM Light works with the .NET Framework 4.5.1. It was released before VS 2015 was released. Will the latest MVVM Light toolkit work within VS 2015 if I create a WPF app using .NET Framework 4.6?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use MVVM Light version 5.2.0.